# How to use python-telegram-bot repository to send message to telegram user request?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I programmed a telegram bot for downloading torrents with python-telegram-bot repository; however, my functions seem to work on the server side and the responses appear on my terminal/console where im running the py-script and transmissionBT server, but it does not send the response back to the user. below is my code:

```
def get_torrent(MAGNET):
    import subprocess
    get_it = subprocess.run(["transmission-remote", "-a", "-D", "-o", "--utp", MAGNET])
    return "*success*"

def list_torrent(LISTED):
    import subprocess
    get_list = subprocess.run(["transmission-remote", LISTED])
    return "*listed*"

def del_torrent(TORRENT_NO):
    import subprocess
    del_torrent = subprocess.run(["transmission-remote", "-t", TORRENT_NO, "-r"])
    return "*deleted*"

def crepttit(bot, update, args):
    import time
    MAGNET = " ".join(args)
    media_content = get_torrent(MAGNET)
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.send_meessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=media_content)

def crepttl(bot, update, args):
    import time
    LISTED  = " ".join(args)
    listed_torrent = list_torrent(LISTED)
    time.sleep(1)
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=torrent_list)

def crepttd(bot, update, args):
    import time
    TORRENT_NO = " ".join(args)
    deleted_torrent = del_torrent(TORRENT_NO) 
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.send_meessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=deleted_torrent)



from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import subprocess
import time
import os
TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
start_handler = CommandHandler("creptt", crepttit, pass_args=True)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
start_handler2 = CommandHandler("crepttl", crepttl, pass_args=True)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler2)
start_handler3 = CommandHandler("crepttd", crepttd, pass_args=True)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler3)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Replace `bot` with `context.bot`

Comment: inside of the function parameters or in the function body?

Comment: or both? def creptt(context.box, update, args)? or context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.caht_id, text=media_content)?

Comment: i tried both and it didn't work. It will return the string on the return function inside function body, but I need it ro return value from response.

Comment: Not both. Replace `bot` with `context` in function parameters, and replace `bot` with `context.bot` in body.

Comment: well, I have actually done that following the p-t-b api; however it doesn't seem to work, thus the reason I am using the old style that semi-works.

Comment: Is this python-telegram-bot module? If the answer is yes, you're using the old syntax. Things like declaring bot and args as parameters in the functions goes no more, now is only update and context. If you still need help edit your question with your current code and questions/problems you still have.

Comment: now i am using the new api.